# After import from Eclipse to Android Studio cannot run Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug"

Tags: android, android-studio, migration, eclipse-adt

Have an Android project working in Eclipse (4.4.2) ADT, running on Linux (Ubuntu 14.10).

I have imported to Android Studio (1.1.0) and managed to get rid of my initial compilation errors.

The next thing I want to d is to run on my phone - I push the green "Run" button and after a little while I get an error (this doesn't show up when I just build module, only when I try to run)

The error is this:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':myapp:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Been looking through SO for the last 4 hours and not found anything that seems relevant to my project. Is there another place I can look to find a more useful error?

**EDIT:** Aaarghh - just recreated the entire project(rather than trusting the import wizard) - I created a new Android Studio project, imported my code and resources and then solved all the compilation and dependency errors. Got through to a clear build then tried to run....same damn error! Exactly the same. What am I doing wrong????

New build.gradle posted for reference:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mycompany.app_Name"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories { mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile project(':swipeListView')
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.8.jar')
compile files('libs/linkedin-j-android.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/core.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.20.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile project(':myImportedProject')
}
```

Also tried to export as an APK with my keystore: got a similar error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexRelease'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!

Seems the answer was further up in trace: The error was

> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;

So I found the answer here:

[ListViewAnimations Library Causes TOP-LEVEL-EXCEPTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414318/listviewanimations-library-causes-top-level-exception)

Part of the trick is not only to add the line to build.gradle saying

```
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
```

but also to remove the JAR from the libs directory.

Now I have more linking issues but I'll leave them for another question I guess.

Comment: which build.gradle do you add this to? the lib or the app? i tried to add either one and both, still didnt help me. have the same problem @Kibi

Comment: In my particular case I added it to the build-gradle of the lib. Basically I had (in Eclipse) an imported project for a "SwipeListView" which had the nineoldandroids jar in its libs directory. Of course it's specific to my case since that was my error. I think my major "insight" here (which isn't too bright) is that the real error was a little further up in the trace. The message "Execution failed for task app:dexDebug" is about as useful as "something bad happened" and should really say "look up higher for the real error."

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you would have to **remove android libraries** which you have in `libs` folder while you were working in EclipseADT. I recommend to remove `android-support-v*.jar` from the `libs` folder after importing it to the Android Studio Directory.