# Error after adding Dropbox Sync API on both Android Studio and Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to make an Android Dropbox Explorer and use Dropbox Sync API. I used Eclipse to do but after the error message I switched to Android Studio, also an error as following:

- **Eclipse:** `

> [2015-03-23 12:42:24 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex
>   files define
>   Lcom/dropbox/client2/android/AuthActivity$SecurityProvider

`

- **A. Studio:**

> Error: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.>
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 2

I don't know how to solve this problem. 
Every reply would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796422/after-import-from-eclipse-to-android-studio-cannot-run-execution-failed-for-task

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tip Satty, but my problem is not just the error when importing project from Eclipse to A. Studio. It's the error on both programs after I add the Dropbox Sync API files to libs folder. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: did you removed jars from your libs directory?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202134969-Error-after-adding-Dropbox-Sync-API-files-to-libs-folder-on-Eclipse-and-Android-Studio ]

Comment: As Greg mentioned in dropbox forum, I just use only one API and it's fine. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio fails to debug with error org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640314/android-studio-fails-to-debug-with-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexcepti)